# Using Principal Component Analysis Based on Sample Covariance? [But really how to get these eigenvalues?]

Tags: self-study, pca, linear-algebra

I have the following sample covariance matrix;

$$
S=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    16 & 10 \\
    10 & 25 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Now to use PCA I know I need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I know how to get the eigenvalues which gives me:

$$\lambda_1 = 31.47 , \lambda_2 = 9.53$$

But how do I get the following eigenvectors?

$(0.54, 0.84)^T$ and $(0.84 , -0.54)$

Can someone do it step by step for me? I thought I knew how to find eigenvalues by, hand but I've always used whole numbers when learning eigenvectors.

EDIT: This is one of the earlier steps to problems involving Principal Component Analysis. My book says, "here are the eigenvalues" and I can confirm that they are the eigenvalues but I have 0 clue how they calculated the eigenvectors. Perhaps I misunderstood PCA?

Comment: Feel free to add the self-study tag

Comment: It seems $(S− \lambda I)x = 0$ has no solution after we plug in eigenvales 
$\frac{41\pm \sqrt{481}}{2}$, Don't know how this is handled numerically

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I wonder if I misunderstood PCA. I thought we just took eigenvectors for the covariance matrix. I'll add a correction if I misunderstood. Otherwise I was able to get eigenvectors but they're not what the book has.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Two-dimensional_matrix_example.  @Deep If you could find no solution, you must have erred in your calculation.

Comment: I read through that link but I'm still getting the wrong answer. I even found online calculators for eigenvectors/eigenvalues which gave different answers (one of which was consistent with my book.
This one Agrees with me: http://www.arndt-bruenner.de/mathe/scripts/engl_eigenwert2.htm

This one agrees with my book: http://comnuan.com/cmnn01002/

Comment: @whuber, thanks, you are right, I did not realize that$ (2.5-\frac{41+\sqrt{481}}{20})*(\frac{41+\sqrt{481}}{2}-16)+10=0$ this makes $x_2$ be anything.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: I added it but I solved my issue. I just had to normalize my vectors.